# Script for multiple time stamps

Tags: google-apps-script

Im trying to have a code that records a timestamp in column "N" case revision started when column "K" (case revised) is modified; that timestamp needs to be copied to column "P"(because whenever column "k" is modified the timestamp changes (need a non editable timestamp for the record).
Then I need that when column "L" is modified, a timestamp is recorded in column "O" Issue cloud (case revision ended).

This is the code im using but cant make it work:

```
function onEdit(e){
  
  multi(e);
  single(e);
}

function single(e) {
    if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== 'Forms' || e.range.rowStart < 1 || e.range.columnStart !== 12) return;
    e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
}
function multi(e) {
  var colsToWatch = [13], colToStamp = 16;
  if (colsToWatch.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) === "true") return;
e.range.offset(0, 4).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");  
}

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const source = ss.getRange('Forms!n2:n');
  const target = ss.getRange('Forms!p2:p');
  source.copyTo(target);{
}
```

Comment: Please ask a single question.

Comment: I'm confused about your question. Can I try and clarify? Please correct me if I am wrong. If column K is edited, you want a "new" timestamp in column N; if there is already a timestamp in Column N, you want that "old" timestamp to be copied to Column P. If column L is edited, you want a "new" timestamp in Column O.